# Textbox Appears According to Button Choice

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, textbox, radio-button

I want a textbox to appear only when a radio-button is chosen. I tried using RadioButtonList but i couldn't get it to work, so I used separate radio buttons. **However, it didn't work.** Here is the code:

```
Protected Sub radItem_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radItem.CheckedChanged
    If radItem.Checked = True Then
        radClient.Checked = False
        radUser.Text = False
        btnSearch.Visible() = True
        txtSearch.Visible() = True
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub radUser_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radUser.CheckedChanged
    If radUser.Checked = True Then
        radItem.Checked = False
        radClient.Text = False
        btnSearch.Visible() = True
        txtSearch.Visible() = True
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub radClient_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radClient.CheckedChanged
    If radClient.Checked = True Then
        radItem.Checked = False
        radUser.Text = False
        btnSearch.Visible() = True
        txtSearch.Visible() = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure there's a much efficient way of doing this anyway.

Comment: Get rid of those ()'s after the .Visible

Comment: Thanks! Just did that, but still not working. The two other buttons won't uncheck, and btnSearch & txtSearch won't appear.

Comment: Why are you setting a TextBox's TextValue to False?

Comment: @FaresA. You said that it didn't work, did you get an error? What did your attempt do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Click Event and since you are handling the same multiple radio buttons

```
Protected Sub rad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radItem.Click, radUser.Click, radClient.Click
     If Ctype(sender, RadioButton).Checked = False Then Exit Sub
     Select Case Ctype(sender, RadioButton).Name
          Case "radItem"
               radUser.Text = False 'You are setting the Text value to False?
                                    'Are you sure about this?

          Case "radUser"
               radClient.Text = False

          Case Else 'radClient
               radUser.Text = False
     End Select

     'You are doing this regardless of which radio button is checked
     radItem.Checked = False 'This is weird. You wont be able to use radItem.

     'I dont think you need this two lines anymore. There is always 1 RadioButton that is checked
     btnSearch.Visible = True
     txtSearch.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ruben! Thanks for your response. The purpose of the False statements is to set the other two to false. To make it simpler, assuming there are two buttons, if button1 is checked, button2 should uncheck, and vice versa!

Comment: By button1, button2 etc, do you mean RadioButtons? You don't have to do that because RadiotButtons will do that automatically.

Comment: What I mean by False Statements are these lines:
`radUser.Text = False
radClient.Text = False
radUser.Text = False`
Why are setting the TextValue to False?

Answer (score 0):

As tymeJV mentioned, remove `()` in the `Visible()`

Also, you do not need to disable other radioButtons, unless they were specifically grouped separately.

Since you are always making button/textbox visible regardless of which radiobutton was selected, you do not need to check for radio button value. Your event should look like this (change others to follow the suit)

```
Protected Sub radItem_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radItem.CheckedChanged
    btnSearch.Visible = True
    txtSearch.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is, they **are** grouped separately because I did not know how to implement the code when it came to grouping them. Any suggestions?

Comment: To group, put them on the same control that can host other controls (such as TABControl, GroupBox, Panel, etc). All radioButtons within that control will be grouped together.

Comment: RadioButtonList does not need grouping. 
for grouping radio buttons, use the property 'GroupName' and set the same Value for radio you want to group

Comment: @MuhammadOmar +1. GroupName property only exists in a web application, not a windows application though. Good call if OP has a web app, GroupName is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Fares, after adding the 'GroupName' property to your radio buttons, you will not need to set the Text or Checked state of the other Radios, it will update automatically.

for Show/Hide Textboxes, you only need to set `txtSearch.Visible() = True` OR `txtSearch.Visible() = False`

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoPostBack property to true in each radio buttons. then it will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @zisoft "Not an answer" should be used only when no attempt is made to answer the question. This answer does not seem correct to me, but even in that case, it should merely be downvoted, not flagged or deleted.